# Can I take a bicycle when boarding a VIA Rail train at a small (flag) stop?

Tags: trains, luggage, canada, bicycles

VIA Rails takes bicycles on trains that have checked baggage, under the [following conditions](http://www.viarail.ca/en/travel-info/baggage/checked-baggage):

> **Bicycles require specific protection.** We recommend that you store your bicycle in a special protective box, which you can obtain free of charge at the station. You’ll need to turn the handlebars and remove the pedals, so bring the necessary tools with you as we cannot supply them.

And:

> **However, if your bicycle is not boxed, VIA Rail accepts no liability in the event of damage.**

On the other hand, they have a long list of special articles accepted on northern routes — including doors, windows, refrigerators and carcasses...

Will VIA Rail accept an unboxed bicycle when boarding at a small stop that does not have a station, much less bicycle boxes?  For example, at one of the many flag stops in Northern Ontario, that lack physical stations.  Can I board a train with my bicycle there?

**Edit:** For clarification, the route through Northern Ontario I'm taking *does* have checked baggage on the train, but the small flag stops I am considering *do not* have any services.

Comment: Note the word "recommend" - my reading of this is that you *can* bring an unboxed bicycle, but if it gets broken, VIA will not compensate you.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the answer is maybe depending on if the train has checked baggage service or not and if your bike is a folding bike or not, according to the website from your post.

http://www.viarail.ca/en/travel-info/baggage/checked-baggage

> The following articles can only be transported if checked baggage
>   service is available on your train. **If there is no checked baggage
>   service, you cannot carry these articles.**
>
> ```
> Pets
> Camping equipment
> Articles exceeding 66 × 46 × 23 cm (26 × 18 × 9 in.)
> Articles weighing more than 23 kg (50 lb.)
> Cradles
> Bicycles
> Canoes, kayaks, sailboards
> Trunks
> ```
>
> **Protecting bicycles**
>
> Bicycles require specific protection. We recommend that you store your bicycle in a special protective box, which you can obtain free of
>   charge at the station. You’ll need to turn the handlebars and remove
>   the pedals, so bring the necessary tools with you as we cannot supply
>   them.
>     If you cannot remove the pedals from your bicycle, we can provide you with a protective bag instead of a box.
>     However, if your bicycle is not boxed, VIA Rail accepts no liability in the event of damage.

The bicycle protection box is only meant to protect VIA because they do not want to take responsibility on damaged bikes. So if you boarding a train that has the service from a remote station which means you cannot get a box

The list about the Northern routes is there to specify unusual items that could be common in those areas. For example, you probably won't see people carrying carcasses in Toronto.

I am not sure which stop you are at but there is also a paragraph about which train you are on

> If your train does not have a baggage car, no checked baggage service
>   will be offered. You will therefore have to comply with the carry-on
>   baggage policy. Please refer to the carry-on baggage section for more
>   details.

The carry on link is http://www.viarail.ca/en/travel-info/baggage/carry-baggage in that page they do mention **folding bicycles** can be carried on as long as it fits that dimension (62 inch linear).

I honestly find some of this or the combination of some of the info confusing. It is best to give them a call so you can ask for specifics.

1-888 VIA RAIL (842-7245)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the website in your answer, for completeness? Does seem like a good answer otherwise.

Comment: I added the link, it's the same one in the question

Comment: @KateGregory the OP mentions the small flagged stops which does not even have a station. Those stops will not have a checked bag service. I imagine it's just a platform that people can get on/off the train.

Comment: @Huangism I disagree. The web site talks about whether the **train** has checked baggage service (eg a baggage car) not the **station** - you're the one concluding it depends on the station and I'm asking you where you see anything to indicate that.

Comment: @KateGregory oh I get what you are saying now, yes you are right I was thinking of the boxes which you get from the station. I will update the answer